# Can a conjunction be the object of the second clause?

Tags: grammar

Can a conjunction be the object of the second clause?
Example:
**Do it wherever you are**

here "wherever" acts as a conjunction and it is the object of the second clause? Am I right?

Comment: *Wherever you are* in that sentence is not a conjunction. I would call it an adverbial phrase.

Comment: @BillJ Now I am online

Comment: The tree diagram in my answer below may help you to understand the structure of the preposition phrase "wherever you are".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Do it wherever you are.*

[image: Tree Diagram of PP IN Fused Relative Construction]

The expression "wherever you are" is a PP (preposition phrase) functioning as an adjunct (a modifier) in the structure of the sentence, which here is of a special kind called a 'fused relative construction'.

Within the PP, the complement of "are" is a locative complement (marked by 'gap') which is cross-indexed with '*i* ' to the head "wherever", called the prenucleus.

Comment: preposition ? The dictionary shows that "wherever" is only a conjunction and an adverb?

Comment: Traditional grammar classifies "where" and "wherever" as relative adverbs in examples like yours, but modern grammar analyses them as prepositions. But it makes no difference to the structure of the tree diagram.

Answer (score 0):

*Wherever* is neither a conjunction nor an object.

The clause *wherever you are* is a fused relative clause acting as a locative adjunct—an adverbial—to the main clause *Do it*.

Syntactically *wherever* is a relativizer signalling a 'gap'—a missing constituent in the clause, to be 'filled in' by the hearer.

> You are _

Semantically, *wherever* is a 'pro-form' standing for a locative preposition phrase in the same way that a pronoun stands for a noun phrase. It's roughly equivalent to *(at) whatever place*, with the determinative *whatever* fused with an implicit locative nominal.

*Whatever* implies then a locative preposition phrase in the gap (marked above by _), which in that clause  would be a predicative complement:

> You are *there*.

Answer (score 0):

Conjunctions cannot be objects.  Objects have to be nouns or noun phrases.

There are words that are somewhat conjunctions and somewhat pronouns - these are relative pronouns.

> I want to know which one do you want.

The *which* works as both a pronoun (filling in the X for *I want to know X*) and conjunction linking *I want to know* to *which one do you want*.

*Wherever* is not a relative pronoun but *where* can be ...

> I looked where he told me to.

Because *wherever* doesn't have a linking function, a *that* can appear there (often elided) if *wherever* is used, but not *where*:

> I looked wherever [that] he told me to.
>
> I looked where that he told me to (doesn't work).

Comment: You said that "Conjunctions cannot be objects" then what is this "He gave me the ball that I wanted" Isn't here "that" acting like a conjunction and object at the same time?

Comment: @BoSsYyY No. Again, this *that* is a relativizer introducing a relative clause which modifies the direct object *the ball*.